# CosmosDB System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'authKeyOrResourceToken')'

Tags: c#, database, azure, connection, azure-cosmosdb

Currently I am getting the following error while trying to connect to my CosmosDB:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'authKeyOrResourceToken')'
```

If I debug then I can see that section variable is `null` so I don't know why it is `null` because I call the section by the configuration with the exact same name of my `appsettings.json`

The error occurs in the following line of code:

```
var section = builder.Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb");
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbService>(
    InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync(section).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

The `InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync` method looks like that:
[image]

In my Visual Studio it looks like that:
[image: description]

My `appsettings.json` looks like that:
[image]

Additionally the error message contains another description:

> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
> Program.$.__InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync|0_0(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection) in Program.cs
> [External Code]
> Program.$(string[]) in Program.cs

Comment: The [Microsoft CosmosDB tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-dotnet-application#initialize-services) could be helpful to you.

Comment: @Cleptus yes I used that tutorial but in .NET6 is the problem you can't use the following line:     services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbService>(InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync(Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb")).GetAwaiter().GetResult());

Comment: I believe you are using the key values instead of key name in your `InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync`. It should be `string account = configurationSection.GetSection("Account").Value;
    string key = configurationSection.GetSection("Key").Value;`.

Comment: @GauravMantri yes that is true and also have to refactor a code down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***IN .NET6 IT IS IMPORTANT TO CONSIDER THAT THERE YOU HAVE TO REFACTOR CODE FROM DOCUMENTATION (.NET5) ACCORDING TO THE .NET6 CODING GUIDLINE!***

I fixed it by refactor the value of the parameters. If I use an appsettings.json then I also have to call these variables in my program.cs.

**New program.cs:**

```
async Task<CosmosDbService> InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync(
        IConfigurationSection configurationSection) {
    var databaseName = configurationSection.GetSection("DatabaseName").Value;
    var containerName = configurationSection.GetSection("ContainerName").Value;
    var accountUri = configurationSection.GetSection("Account").Value;
    var primaryKey = configurationSection.GetSection("authKey").Value;
    var client = new CosmosClient(accountUri, primaryKey);
    var cosmosDbService = new CosmosDbService(client, databaseName, containerName);
    var database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
    await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName, "/id");
    return cosmosDbService;
}

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbService>(InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync(
builder.Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb")).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```